# Trigger google chatbot without mention

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way to trigger a Google chat bot in a space without mentioning it? Like if you write "what's the wifi password" it uses the include("wifi") and sends a message?

It only works in DM, but in a space you need to @mention it.

Thanks in advance!
Best regards Max

Answer (score -1):

Probably a sample of your code could give us an idea on how you are calling the bot, however just for reference. You should be able to configure the space type to "ROOM".

As suggested by the sample code from the [event](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/message-formats/events#added_to_space) article for developers:

```html
{
  "type": "ADDED_TO_SPACE",
  "eventTime": "2017-03-02T19:02:59.910959Z",
  "space": {
    "name": "spaces/AAAAAAAAAAA",
    "displayName": "Customer Support Superstars",
    "type": "ROOM"
  }
```

I also was able to find a project information utilizing webhooks to accomplish something similar to yours

**Reference**

- https://github.com/jdw353/google-workspace-apps-script-toolbox/blob/master/google-chat-updates-bot/code.js

Comment: I was a little bit unclear in my main post, what I mean is if there is a way to trigger OnMessage for every message in a room without mentioning the bot